# java servlet test with different URLs

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets

I want to test my Servlet with different incoming URLs. I tried to use Mockito to test if specific function was called:

```
package servlet;

import blabla;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"})
public class MainServletTest extends TestCase{

    @Autowired
    private Categories categories;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Mock
    private HttpSession session;

    @Mock
    private RequestDispatcher rd;

    @Test
    public void testCategories() throws ServletException, IOException {
        // given
        request.setServerName("localhost");//here I try to change incoming URL
        request.setRequestURI("/test/categories");//here I try to change incoming URL
        HttpServletRequest req = spy(request);//???
        //when
        new MainServlet().doGet(req, response);


        //then
        verify(req).setAttribute("categories", categories.getContainer());//here try to check if this method is called
    }
}
```

Here I try to change incoming url and check if specific attribute was set for incoming request. Since **req** is not *Mock* object but *MockHttpServletRequest* object - this code does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Either use a mock:

```
// ...

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest request;

// ...

@Test
public void testCategories() throws ServletException, IOException {
    // given
    when(request.getServerName()).thenReturn("localhost");
    when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("/test/categories")
    //when
    new MainServlet().doGet(req, response);
    //then
    verify(req).setAttribute("categories", categories.getContainer());
```

**or**

Use [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) to check the attribute named `categories`:

```
assertEquals(categories.getContainer(), req.getAttributes("categories"));
```